Can an APK be installed from a URI via `adb`?
Question

As an example, I've tried the undermentioned:
adb -s "$DeviceName" install -t 'https://github.com/HomeZz/Current-Activity/releases/download/v1.5.9/app-debug-v1.5.9.apk'

However, this fails:

Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to stat https://github.com/HomeZz/Current-Activity/releases/download/v1.5.9/app-debug-v1.5.9.apk: No such file or directory


Does anyone know of an alternative method which eliminates the necessity to download the .APK first?
Rationale


I ask because when prototyping APKs on a device from multiple locations online - which is something that I commonly do - needing to download them first - especially over a slow internet connection - can be bothersome.

When I first tried, I was surprised that this failed, because dnf5 install "$URI" is perfectly valid and normal.



You can directly download and install APK files inside the adb shell. Equip your Android phone with a tool like curl (e.g. extract it from Termux), download the APK file into Android flash storage and then install it using pm command (the same would be possible on PC side). IMHO you are simply dissatisfied by your manually process of installing APK files but don't want to spend the effort to automate it.

@Robert, why on Earth would you assume that I've no desire to "spend the effort to automate it"? I've provided no insight into what, more broadly, I'm trying to accomplish, nor my efforts toward it, because they're irrelevant. Irrespective, I'm thankful for the advice to use curl. However, the reason I'd not considered curl or wget to be an answer is because I use a multitude of devices that I can't necessarily modify willy-nilly. Being able to use adb (or pm, if I don't need to add any binaries) would be more convenient.

@RokeJulianLockhart pm is standard on Android devices, and wget is available in busybox (though it only supports http or ftp, not https). So adb shell 'cd /data/local/tmp ; busybox wget http://wherever/the.apk ; pm install -r /data/local/tmp/the.apk' works well. But you need a non-https server.

@jcaron, are you referring to https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/8917? I see issues on GitHub that would appear to indicate that BusyBox does support HTTPS. Is this an AOSP-specific deficiency? Thanks for the examples.

@RokeJulianLockhart I meant "the version of busybox in Android", or at least on the tablets I tried it on (quite a small sample, so this may not be universal, and may depend on the Android version and/or on build settings).

A bit of reading the ADB source reveals that no, there isn't another way with ADB. As of today, the key function that does the work is do_sync_push() in file_sync_client.cpp and that does an ordinary stat() call on the source file(s).
The adb install processing is quite simple: push the APK to /data/local/tmp, invoke pm on it, and then delete the pushed copy of the  APK.
ADB could doubtless be extended to do this, and it's possible to make requests and report bugs against it. I suspect it doesn't have all the bells and whistles of dnf5 simply because a lot fewer people use it.

Thanks for this. I've filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/363984099#comment1 consequently.
